# Disable A Button If It's Already Been Clicked In The Current Month

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp.net` random generator web application which has a button which dos my random stuff and displays the result in a field and writes it to my db and displays in a table on the website.

I have been told though that this button should only be allowed to be clicked once a month so once it has been clicked it shouldn't be allowed again.

The problem i have with this is that i have no idea on how to do this at all as i am fairly new to dev.

I know that all i need to look for is the month. I have provided my HTML and code behind for what i have at the moment.

**HTML**

```
     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtDestination" runat="server" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <% if (txtDestination.Text == "")
                    {%>
                        <asp:Button class="btn btn-success" ID="BtnDecideForMe" runat="server" Text="Decide For Me" OnClick="BtnDecideForMe_Click" />
                    <%}
                    else
                    { %>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" disabled>Decided</button>
                    <%} %>
                </div>
            </div>    
<asp:GridView ID="tblPastPlaces" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlPastPlaces" GridLines="None" Width="30%">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Past_Place" HeaderText="Past Place" SortExpression="Past_Place" HeaderStyle-Width="60%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Month" HeaderText="Month" SortExpression="Month" />
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPastPlaces" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PaydayLunchConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="GetPastPlaces" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Past_Places] ([Past_Place], [Month], [Click_Date]) VALUES (@Past_Place, @Month, @Click_Date)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Past_Place" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="String" Name="Month" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Click_Date" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Code**

```
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Past_Place"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)txtDestination).Text;
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Month"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Click_Date"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
SqlPastPlaces.Insert();
```

Comment: From my point of view, a month is a long duration so you can't handle this with sessions, cookies. What you can do is, when button is clicked first time save that instance (time-stamp) in database. When form is being rendered, check time-stamp and accordingly enable disable that.

Comment: @AbhimanyuKumarVatsa I am writing to my db when the actual date the button is being clicked but i'm a little confused on your other suggestion. Would it be possible for you to provide some code as an answer for me so i can see what your doing please

Comment: Are only authorized users able to click the button? Or can anyone that visits the site click the button?

Comment: @murday1983 Where do you have the button? Is it within the GridView or is on page directly?

Comment: @PierreNortje At the moment anyone can click the button but going forward it may only be a selection of users.

Comment: @SivaGopal The button is outside the gridview.  I have updated my HTML with it

Comment: So are you struck on how to compare the current month to the month of last clicked Date stored in database?

Comment: @SivaGopal Yes. i have no idea on how to know if the button has been clicked in the current month or not.  In my db i have 2 columns a Month which get the `datetime.now` and formats it as 'October and also a month clicked column which displays the normal date structure (2015-01-01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed it by getting the value from my DB then adding a hidden `label` and using that to match to `datetime.now.tostring("MMMM")`

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Returns the last month entry from the Past_Places table so can disable the button if it has been run for the current month
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT        TOP (1) Month " +
                "FROM          Past_Places", conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    PastMonth.Text = reader["Month"].ToString();
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
    <div class="row">
        <asp:Label ID="PastMonth" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtDestination" runat="server" disabled></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <% if (PastMonth.Text.Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")))
            { %>
              <button class="btn btn-success" disabled>Already Done For This Month</button>
            <%}
            else if (txtDestination.Text == "")
            {%>
                <asp:Button class="btn btn-success" ID="BtnDecideForMe" runat="server" Text="Decide For Me" OnClick="BtnDecideForMe_Click" />
            <%}
            else
            { %>
                <button class="btn btn-success" disabled>Decided</button>
            <%} %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compare month in last clicked date in database to the current month, you can do something like:

```
string lastClickDateValue = GetMonthClickedFromDatabase(); //Connect to database and get the value within this method
DateTime lastClickDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lastClickDateValue);

if(lastClickDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
{
     btnMonth.Enabled = false; //Button ID you want to disable
}
```

This code is to provide you some idea and you can try with the exact logic you need.